# declaring static dictionary in Java

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way to declare hashMap or hashTable as static but not final? 
I want to be able to update it and therefor I don't want it to be final..

If not, what other way can I create a static dictionary?

Comment: Did you try `public static Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();` ?

Comment: what are you saying ...does not make any sense..please clearly specify what you are trying to achieve doing what..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but most likely you don't need to make it non final.

When you make a *reference* final it is only that reference, not the object you reference to which cannot be changed.

e.g.

```
static final Map<String, String> map = ...

map.put("Hello", "world"); // is okay
map = new HashMap<>();     // not okay
```

BTW it is generally not good practice to have global/static collections.  You should limit access to such a collection as much as possible and ensure it is thread safe unless you know this is not required. e.g. instead of making the collection public, you can do

```
private static final Map<String, String> map = ...

public static synchronized void put(String key, String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}  

public static synchronized String get(String key) {
    return map.get(key);
}
```